# (iOS) Navigator.mediaDevices not present in your browser error with ionic and aframe

Tags: ionic-framework, aframe, ar.js

I can't get AR.JS or Aframe to work with Ionic on iOS.

I get the following error `Webcam error: WebRTC issue-! Navigator.mediaDevices not present in your browser` when trying to build for iOS. Is there something I'm missing?

I've followed this example https://www.joshmorony.com/augmented-reality-in-an-ionic-angular-pwa/

Answer (score 3):

Some APIs like `getUserMedia` are not available in iOS WebViews (that I suspect Ionic uses). Those
APIs are only availbe in Safari proper. More info: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3892

Comment: That's a shame. Is there another good alternative to get AR working in Ionic?